# How do I specify which version of a Gstreamer plugin to use when I have multiple Gstreamer installations?

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, python-gstreamer

I have several Gstreamer 1.16 plugins at `/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0`.
I have several Gstreamer 1.21 plugins at `/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0`.

I have a custom Python "app" (that I cannot make changes to) running a pipeline with the `rtpbin` element from the `libgstrtpmanager.so` plugin file, which exists both in the 1.16 and 1.21 paths. Gstreamer is preferring the 1.16 version of the plugin, which is causing errors in my "app", as it is expecting some signal functionalities only available in the 1.21 version.

**Other than deleting/hiding the 1.16 version of the file, how do I specify that Gstreamer should prefer the 1.21 version of the plugin?**

I have tried exporting the paths to `$GST_PLUGIN_PATH`, with the 1.21 path first, but that did not work.

Comment: Futher than setting GST_PLUGIN_PATH, you may adjust PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Delete gstreamer cache (such as `~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/registry.aarch64.bin` for aarch64 architecture) and then try `gst-inspect-1.0 --version`